# PDF Fill-In Forms created in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have used  [TCPDF](http://tcpdf.org/) in the past to generate PDF's on-the-fly. Now I need to create a Form in PDF that would allow the user to enter data locally and then print/save the PDF locally.

Which **free** PDF library should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Reader will only save files that were **signed with an appropriate license key** from Adobe, such as one provided with LiveCycle Reader Extensions.

While you could find free software to sign your documents, you would still need to get a license key from Adobe or a reseller.

Answer (score 0):

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) seems to be good these days for those looking for open-source solution.

Comment: Are you sure it allows for forms? I didn't see anything like that in the manual...